# What is new in version 1.5 of the BlackBerry Plugin for Eclipse?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have searched the [BlackBerry website](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/36684/index.jsp?name=Release%20Notes%20-%20BlackBerry%20Java%20Plug-in%20for%20Eclipse%20for%20the%20BlackBerry%20Java%20SDK%207.1%20Beta1.5&language=English&userType=21&category=BlackBerry%20Java%20Plug-in%20for%20Eclipse&subCategory=) and [developer forum](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/forums/searchpage/tab/message?q=eclipse%20plugin%201.5#/?sort_by=-topicPostDate&q=eclipse%20plugin%201.5&search_type=thread) for any details about this new version of the plugin but details are non-existent. Can someone who's done the upgrade shed some light on whether it's worth upgrading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/35148/BlackBerry_Java_Plug-in_for_Eclipse-Release_Notes--1884636-1018081901-001-1.5-US.pdf

That seems to be what you're looking for.

Comment: Many thanks. For the sake of anyone else who's looking for this the key points are: 1) The BlackBerry® Java® Plug-in is supported for use wtih Eclipse Indigo. 2) The BlackBerry Java Plug-in for Eclipse can now be installed from a separate update site into an existing Eclipse installation. 3) When loading code onto a device, the .jad file is now specified instead of the individual .cod files

Comment: The web version (rather than PDF) is here: http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/35147/New_in_this_release_1.3_1884640_11.jsp